Solving difficult coupled PDEs with DSolve
I have used mathematica to find a set of dynamical equations with boundary conditions. I wonder if it's possible to solve these equations with DSolve. Could anyone help me with this?
Here are my sets of equations for unknown functions $c0(x,z,t)$,$u0(x,z,t)$,$U0(x,z,t)$:
Boundary conditions are
     Derivative[0, 1, 0][c0][x, h, t] == 0
G*Derivative[0, 1, 0][u0][x, h, t] + 
   \[Mu]*Derivative[0, 1, 1][u0][x, h, 
     t] == 0
Derivative[0, 3, 0][c0][x, h, t] == 0
(\[Zeta]*c0[x, h, t]^2)/
    (1 + k*c0[x, h, t]^2) + 
   (2*G + \[Lambda])*Derivative[0, 1, 0][U0][
     x, h, t] + (2*\[Mu] + \[CapitalMu])*
    Derivative[0, 1, 1][U0][x, h, t] + 
   \[Lambda]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][u0][x, h, 
     t] + \[CapitalMu]*Derivative[1, 0, 1][u0][
     x, h, t] == Derivative[1, 0][h][
    x, t]*(G*Derivative[0, 1, 0][u0][
      x, h, t] + 
    \[Mu]*Derivative[0, 1, 1][u0][x, h, 
      t])

Derivative[0, 0, 1][u0][x, 0, t] == 0
(Derivative[0, 0, 1][U0][x, 0, t]) == 0; 
(Derivative[0, 1, 0][c0][x, z, t] == 
     0 /. z -> 0) == 0; 
(Derivative[0, 0, 1][U0][x, z, t] /. 
    z -> h) == 
   (Derivative[0, 0, 1][u0][x, z, t]*
      Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t] + 
     Derivative[0, 1][h][x, t] /. 
    z -> h); 
(Derivative[1, 1, 0][u0][x, z, t] + 
     Derivative[0, 2, 0][U0][x, z, 
      t] /. z -> 0) == 0; 

The equations are
G*Derivative[0, 2, 0][u0][x, z, t] + 
   \[Mu]*Derivative[0, 2, 1][u0][x, z, 
     t] == 0;
(2*\[Zeta]*c0[x, z, t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][
       c0][x, z, t])/
    (1 + k*c0[x, z, t]^2)^2 + 
   (B + G)*Derivative[0, 2, 0][U0][x, 
     z, t] + (\[Mu] + \[CapitalMu])*
    Derivative[0, 2, 1][U0][x, z, t] + 
   B*Derivative[1, 1, 0][u0][x, z, 
     t] + \[CapitalMu]*Derivative[1, 1, 1][u0][
     x, z, t] == 0;
Derivative[0, 4, 0][c0][x, z, t] == 0;

The solution for the functions $c0,u0,U0$ should be written with unknown constants, as we don't have the boundary condition in x and t.
For example, I solved these equations for c0 by hand and found a solution c0=c0[x,t]. So the goal is to find the dependence on z.

Is (Derivative[0, 1, 0][c0][x, z, t] == 0 /. z -> 0) == 0 correct?  Also, is h a variable or a constant?

@bbgodfrey h is a constant. The piece of code you refer to is just $\partial_z c_0|_{z=h}=0$

One of your boundary conditions contains Derivative[1, 0][h][x, t], suggesting that h is not a constant.

h is not a constant but is a dynamical boundary @bbgodfrey

Also, why do you think that this system of equations even has a symbolic solution?

such as any other PDE system, i assume they have. @bbgodfrey

In fact, most PDE systems do not have symbolic solutions, only numerical ones.

The solution to the system of PDEs can be obtained for constant h as follows.  For convenience, designate the nine boundary conditions in the order given in the question as bc and the three PDEs as eq.  The third pde and associated boundary conditions can be solved without difficulty:
solc = DSolve[{eq[[3]], bc[[{1, 3, 7}]]}, c0, {x, z, t}, GeneratedParameters -> c][[1, 1]]
(* c0 -> Function[{x, z, t}, c[1][x, t]] *)

Thus, c0 is independent of z but otherwise arbitrary.  Inserting this result into eq[[;; 2]] reduces them to linear PDEs with constant coefficients, which often are easy to solve.  Not so here.
DSolveValue[eq[[;; 2]] /. solc, {u0[x, z, t], U0[x, z, t]}, {x, z, t}]

returns unevaluated.  Instead, try
DSolveValue[eq[[1]], u0[x, z, t], {x, z, t}, GeneratedParameters -> u] 
    /. u[i_][t, x] -> u[i][x, t]
(* Inactive[Integrate][Inactive[Integrate][E^(-((G t)/μ)) u[1][x, K[1]],
   {K[1], 1, K[2]}], {K[2], 1, z}] + u[2][x, t] + z u[3][x, t] *)

This cumbersome expression can, in principle, be simplified by replacing (with no loss of generality) u[1][x, z] by D[u[1][x, z], z, z].  However, Integrate seems unable to do the resulting trivial integrations.  Instead, replace the definite integrals by indefinite integrals, again with no loss of generality.
Activate[% /. K[1] -> z /. {_, 1, _} -> z /.u[1][x, z] -> D[u[1][x, z], z, z]]

and in preparation for the next computation
solu = u0 -> Function[{x, z, t}, Evaluate@%] /. u[1][x, z] -> 
    D[u[1][x, z], z] /. u[3][x, t] -> E^(-(((B + G) t)/(μ + M))) D[u[3][x, t], t];

eq[[1]] /. solu
(* True *)

Solve eq[[3]] in the same way
DSolveValue[eq[[2]] /. solc /. solu, U0[x, z, t], {x, z, t}, 
    GeneratedParameters -> U] /. U[i_][t, x] -> U[i][x, t];
Activate[% /. K[1] -> z /. {_, 1, _} -> z /. U[1][x, z] -> 
    D[U[1][x, z], z, z]] // Simplify
solU = U0 -> Function[{x, z, t}, Evaluate@%];

(* U[1][x, z]/E^(((B + G)*t)/(μ + M)) + U[2][x, t] + z*U[3][x, t] - 
   Derivative[1, 0][u[1]][x, z]/E^((G*t)/μ) - 
   (z^2*((B*μ - G*M)*Derivative[1, 0][u[3]][x, t] + M*(μ + M) 
   *Derivative[1, 1][u[3]][x, t]))/(2*E^(((B + G)*t)/(μ + M))*(μ + M)^2) *)

Simplify[eq[[2]] /. solc /. solu /. solU]
(* True *)

With the PDEs solved, next apply the remaining six boundary conditions.
bc1 = Thread[Subtract @@@ DeleteCases[Simplify[bc /. solc /. solu /. solU],
    True] == 0] /. D[h[x, t], x] -> 0 /. D[h[x, t], t] -> 0;

(As stated earlier, this solution assumes h is constant.)  Although eq1 is too long to reproduce here, three of the equations can be solved and, after further manipulation, so can the other three.
solu3 = DSolve[bc1[[1]], u[3], {x, t}, GeneratedParameters -> u3][[1, 1]]
(* u[3] -> Function[{x, t}, (E^((t (B μ - G M))/(μ (μ + M))) μMu] (μ + M) 
   u3[1][x])/(B μ - G M) + u3[2][x]] *)

solu2 = DSolve[bc1[[3]], u[2], {x, t}, GeneratedParameters -> u2][[1, 1]]
(* u[2] -> Function[{x, t}, u2[1][x] - Derivative[0, 1][u[1]][x, 0] 
   /E^((G*t)/μ)] *)

solU2 = DSolve[bc1[[4]], U[2], {x, t}, GeneratedParameters -> U2][[1, 1]]
(* U[2] -> Function[{x, t}, (-E^(-(((B + G)*t)/(μ + M))))*U[1][x, 0] + 
   U2[1][x] + Derivative[1, 0][u[1]][x, 0]/E^((G*t)/μ)] *)

bc2 = Thread[Subtract @@@ 
    DeleteCases[Simplify[bc1 /. solu3 /. solu2 /. solU2], True] == 0];

DSolveValue[bc2[[3]], u3[2][x], x];
Activate[% /. K[1] -> x /. {_, 1, _} -> x] // Simplify;
solu32 = u3[2] -> Function[{x}, Evaluate@%]
(* u3[2] -> Function[{x}, C[1] + ((μ + M)^2*Integrate[Derivative[0, 2]
   [U[1]][x, 0], x])/(B*μ - G*M)] *)

bc3 = Thread[Subtract @@@ DeleteCases[Simplify[bc2 /. solu32], True] == 0];

solU3 = DSolve[bc3[[2]], U[3], {x, t}, GeneratedParameters -> U3][[1, 1]]
(* U[3] -> Function[{x, t}, U3[1][x] + (E^((G*t)/μ)*(2*U[1][x, 0] - 2*U[1] 
   [x, h] + h^2*Derivative[0, 2][U[1]][x, 0]) + E^(((B + G)*t)/(μ + M))*
   (h^2*Derivative[1][u3[1]][x] - 2*Derivative[1, 0][u[1]][x, 0] + 
   2*Derivative[1, 0][u[1]][x, h]))/(2*E^((t*(B*μ + G*(2*μ + M)))/(μ*(μ + M)))*h)] *)

Simplify[bc3[[1]] /. solU3];
Simplify[Solve[% /. c[1][x, t]^2 -> v, v][[1, 1]]] /. v -> c[1][x, t]^2

This final expression for c[1][x, t]^2 is much too large to reproduce here.  In summary, there are not nearly enough boundary conditions to determine the many remaining functions of x in the solution.

What do you mean by $h$ is constant? do you mean that it is not a function of (x,t)?

@questionerno8 Yes.  I do not have time to try to solve the more general problem.  Also, no solution would be complete without more boundary conditions.

@questionerno8 Probably. 11 boundary conditions are needed, even for constant h.
